# The derivative of a tangent vector having identified vectors as directional derivatives

Tags: calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, vectors, partial-derivative

In introductory calculus, we learn to take derivatives of vectors. For instance, in Cartesian, we have the basis vectors $\vec{e}_x, \vec{e}_y$ and in polars we have $\vec{e}_\rho, \vec{e}_\theta$ given by
$$
\vec{e}_\rho=\cos\theta \: \vec{e}_x + \sin\theta \: \vec{e}_y \\
\vec{e}_\theta=\cos\theta \: \vec{e}_y - \sin\theta \: \vec{e}_x 
$$

Taking derivatives, we get $\partial_x \vec{e}_x = \partial_x \vec{e}_y = \partial_y \vec{e}_x = \partial_y \vec{e}_y = \vec{0}$ and we can differentiate polars as follows:

\begin{align}
\partial_\theta \vec{e}_\rho
&=\partial_\theta \left( \cos\theta \:\vec{e}_x + \sin\theta \:\vec{e}_y \right) \\
&= -\sin\theta \:\vec{e}_x + \cos\theta \:\partial_\theta (\vec{e}_x)+ \cos\theta \:\vec{e}_y +\sin\theta \:\partial_\theta (\vec{e}_y) \\
&=\vec{e}_\theta
\end{align}

Fair enough. This all seems reasonable and the idea that the derivative of a basis vector with respect to the coordinates can be written as some linear combination of the basis vectors seems obvious.

My question is, how can I arrive at the same conclusions having identified basis vectors with the [set of partial derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Tangent_vectors_as_directional_derivatives). If $\vec{e}_x \to \partial_x$, why should $\partial_x \vec{e}_x \to \partial_x \partial_x = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}=0$? I'm confused. More worrying still, using the polar example, I am getting

\begin{align}
\partial_\theta \vec{e}_\rho
\to\partial_\theta \partial_\rho
= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta \partial \rho} \neq \partial_ \theta
\end{align}

I can't seem to reconcile any of this. It is also not at all obvious to me why the derivatives of basis vectors (partial derivatives) should be vectors - aren't they second derivatives?

Grateful for any help...

Comment: Isn't the idea that $\vec {\bf e}_x=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$?

Comment: @AntoniParellada I believe so, yes. Is that not what I have put? I use $\partial _x$ as short hand for $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ to save typing.

Comment: If you identify vectors with partial derivatives then $\partial_x(e_x)=\partial_x ( \partial_x) = 0$, since $\partial_x$ "doesn't depend on the position". To be more formal what should be looking at is commutators of vectors, ie something like $\partial_x (e_x (f)) - e_x(\partial_x (f)) = \partial_x\partial_x f - \partial_x \partial_x f=0$.

Comment: "I can't seem to reconcile any of this. It is also not at all obvious to me why the derivatives of basis vectors (partial derivatives) should be vectors - aren't they second derivatives?" You will find it very helpful to check that if $D, D'$ are derivations (ie $D(f\cdot g) = f\cdot D(g) + D(f)\cdot g$) then $f\mapsto D(D'(f)) - D'(D(f))$ also has the property of a derivation. Your troubles in a way express the fact that a "vector field applied to a vector field" doesn't have a way of making sense. What you have to look at is the commutator of two vector fields, also called the Lie derivative